# Do winged kobolds carry a pouch of rocks?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, ranged-attack, kobold, ammunition

In my adventure I want to add some winged kobolds, but I don't know how their "Dropped Rock" attack works.

Do they carry a pouch of rocks, or they need to pick up larger rocks from the ground every other round?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Good first question! (Also, I didn't notice until just now that their statblock specifies "one target directly below the kobold" in lieu of any range at all.)

Comment: [Related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56449/15469).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### It's usually assumed that a monster carries ammunition for its ranged attacks.

From the intro to the *Monster Manual* (p. 11), under ["Ammunition"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Ammunition):

> A monster carries enough ammunition to make its ranged attacks. You can assume that a monster has 2d4 pieces of ammunition for a thrown weapon attack, and 2d10 pieces of ammunition for a projectile weapon such as a bow or crossbow.

The Dropped Rock attack of the winged kobold would be a thrown weapon attack, so it could be safely assumed that it carries 2d4 stones.

### However, as DM you can always choose to rule differently.

If you decide that a winged kobold can only carry the weight of one rock in flight, you can rule that they need to land and pick up a new rock between attacks.  This may make them a little easier to defeat, as landing will bring the kobolds into range of the party's melee fighters.