# Does a creature polymorphed into a Giant Ape carry ammunition to make its ranged attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, polymorph, ammunition

The description of the [*polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) spell (BR, p. 266) says:

> The target's game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the chosen beast. It retains its alignment and personality.

The [Ammunition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Ammunition) section of the rules on monsters (MM, p. 12; BR, p. 114) says:

> A monster carries enough ammunition to make its ranged attacks. You can assume that a monster has 2d4 pieces of ammunition for a thrown weapon attack, and 2d10 pieces of ammunition for a projectile weapon such as a bow or crossbow.

The [Giant Ape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-ape) statblock (MM, p. 323) includes the Rock attack:

> ***Rock.*** *Ranged Weapon Attack:* +9 to hit, range 50/100 ft., one target. *Hit:* 30 (7d6 + 6) bludgeoning damage.

If a creature's game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the chosen beast when polymorphed, does a character polymorphed into a Giant Ape carry rocks on him to make its rock attack once transformed?

Comment: [Highly related.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/151003/15469)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### No, the rocks are not part of the creature.

Polymorph can turn you into an ape, but it doesn't turn you into an ape and a pile of rocks. The rocks are carried items.

Like all of the 5e rules, the MM's suggestion that a monster carries "enough ammunition" applies to normal cases, not every possible edge case. A [Guard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/guard) carries a spear, but you can still run into a particular guard who for whatever reason doesn't have one right now.