# Does the weight of the grapplee factor into the speed the grappler can drag them?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, grapple, forced-movement, encumbrance

Does the weight of the grapplee (the one being grappled) factor into the speed the grappler can drag them? Or conversely, is a low strength grappler limited by their dragging/listing capacity when forcibly moving their graplee?

My medium-sized character has 8 strength, so the maximum weight she can carry is \$8\times 15 = 160lbs\$, and her drag weight limit is \$8\times 30 = 240lbs\$. She weighs (plus equipment) over 240lbs as well, so I can also ask about a different character trying to grapple her with only just enough strength to drag/push/list but not outright carry her (~less than 16 strength).

The relevant rules for **[Lifting and Carrying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#LiftingandCarrying)**:

> **Carrying Capacity.** Your carrying capacity is your Strength score multiplied by 15. This is the weight (in pounds) that you can carry, which is high enough that most characters don't usually have to worry about it.
>
> **Push, Drag, or Lift.** You can push, drag, or lift a weight in pounds up to twice your carrying capacity (or 30 times your Strength score). While pushing or dragging weight in excess of your carrying capacity, your speed drops to 5 feet.

See also the variant rules for **[Encumbrance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#VariantEncumbrance)**, which I am not playing with currently, but still worth considering.

And under **[Grappling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Grappling)**:

> **Moving a Grappled Creature.** When you move, you can drag or carry the grappled creature with you, but your speed is halved, unless the creature is two or more sizes smaller than you.

So is dragging in a grapple the same as the dragging mentioned in carrying capacity rules? That is do you need to factor the halving of speed before or after (Or at all?) setting it to 5ft, and with the variant rules before or after reducing it by 10ft/20ft when applicable?

I ask, because narratively I don't tend to think of creatures that are 'dragged' in a grapple as being *dragged across the floor* (which is what I assume the carrying capacity rules mean), more being sumo wrestlers force-walking each other around a ring.

#### Carrying Capacity vs. Grapple dragging:

As a visual aid, this is the difference I'm envisioning, which is why I don't think this is so cut an dry.

[image: dog with paws splayed out pulled along with a leash] [image: Sumo wrestlers grappling, one of whom forces the other back and out of the ring]

Comment: I found this related question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/169971/2788 but it doesn't have a satisfying/accurate answer, as well as not considering my dog vs sumo comparison.

Comment: At least related: "[How far can you drag a grappled, heavy opponent?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/169971)" and "[Does carrying/dragging a willing/unconscious creature cause half movement as per the grapple rules?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/117423)" and "[Can a Huge bird \(STR 15, <1000 lbs) really fly off with a Gargantuan Brontosaurus \(>30000 lbs)?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/133918)"

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I’m really not seeing a difference in the two questions. I agree that the answer on the other question isn’t satisfying, but I think this is more of a bounty situation than a new question situation.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov that's completely fair, but a) I spent an hour writing and wording this carefully (and making the GIFs small enough for SE *disgruntled face* ಠ_ಠ) and b) I was hoping this would end up being the better worded question so could be the dupe target

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Thank you filing a claim with Markov Question Insurance. An underwriter will review your claim shortly.

Comment: I have posted an answer on the putative duplicate question.  Perhaps you will find it more satisfying?

Comment: I would be happy to move my answer there, to here, modified accordingly, if this does indeed become the type question.